# Jobname of inputted file?

Tags: expansion, input, jobname

```
\begin{filecontents}{foo.tex}
\def\foo{\jobname}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\input{foo}
\foo
\end{document}
```

This outputs the jobname of the *main file* not "foo". How can I define a macro that outputs the jobname of the inputted file?

`\edef` doesn't work either.

Comment: Try `\@currname`, maybe?

Comment: @Bruno That works! Thanks. Could you make that an answer?

Comment: @Bruno actually, it doesn't I got confused.

Comment: @Bruno, @Seamus: `\@currname` is only valid inside packages or classes and holds the name of this package or class. It is empty otherwise.

Comment: @Martin: I did say "maybe" ;-). Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the package [`currfile`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/currfile), which keeps track of the file name of the input file in the macros

```
\currfiledir
\currfilebase
\currfileext
\currfilename
\currfilepath
```

Furthermore, `\edef` has to be used to expand these values within the input file, not when you are back in the main file:

```
\begin{filecontents}{foo.tex}
\edef\foo{\currfilebase}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{currfile}
\begin{document}
\input{foo}
\foo
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice answer. @Seamus: It is also possible to do `\let\foo\currfilebase`. Note that all the mentioned macros hold the corresponding strings directly without expanding to further macros, e.g. `\currfilepath` doesn't call `\currfiledir\currfilename`. So using `\expandafter` on them will expand the string directly. See also the `filehook` package used by `currfile` and written be the same author (me), which allows you to execute such commands for every input file automatically.

Comment: @Martin Thanks! looks like a good package. Can I take this opportunity to admonish you for not having a "how to install" in your `README` (I know it's a simple `.dtx` but I still think you should have a boilerplate "how to install a dtx" text in your readme...)

Comment: @Seamus: It is part of TeXLive and MikTeX, so no manual install is required. I think I put some INSTALL section into my first packages, but stopped with this habit. I will add some info.

Comment: @Martin unfortunately it is not in the ubuntu version of TL09. I really need to get rid of that and install 2010 myself...

Comment: @Seamus: Either compile the `.ins` file to convert the `.dtx` to `.sty` or install(=unpack) the [TDS ZIP file](http://mirror.ctan.org/install/macros/latex/contrib/currfile.tds.zip) instead.

Comment: @Martin ah thanks. Forgot about TDS. I had to install filehook as well. But it works now.